# Theano Rarely Using GPU

Tags: neural-network, gpu, theano

Just getting started with Theano and my GTX 960, but when training a network (specifically recurrent regression) and GPU usage spikes up for less than a second, maybe two or three times throughout the several minutes it takes. Is there a way to force it to actually use the GPU the entire time?

Seems to take an obscenely long time for not much data.

Answer (score 1):

What is actually happening in your code is that much of the time is spent getting data onto and off of the GPU, but any GPU monitor will show that the GPU is "not being used" during this time, even though what it is doing is loading data. You can't avoid doing this, other than being smart about how and when you load data onto the GPU. The spikes you are describing are completely normal - that is when the GPU actually does the computation. Nothing you can do!

Comment: In such a situation as you are describing, where the data transfer dominates the computation time, it would probably be faster to train on the CPU in the first place.

Comment: Not necessarily - you still need to get the data onto your GPU. The thing that takes the longest is reading files from disk, then getting them where they need to go physically on the board.

Comment: I'm coming from a MatLab NN background and it had no problems loading data to the GPU nearly instantaneously. I don't suspect the minute delay is being caused by having to copy 1.5Mb of data from RAM to my GPU...

Comment: Do you have a minimal code sample that reproduces your problem, in that case? If you do, can you update your original post with the code, and I'll take a look at it.